# Convert EDT timestamp to PST with regex / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, timestamp

A third party is providing me with an EDT time-stamp in the following format:

MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm

*for instance: '08/19/2013 11:31'*

I need to convert it to PST with JavaScript (same date time format) and have been looking all over but can't find any info about doing this.. If someone can help me with some example code I would really appreciate it.

Comment: There are plenty of Date libraries out there to do this. But you could parse the string: split by a space, so you have date and time. Then split the time by ":" and split the date by "/". Create a `new Date()` and provide the right values in the right order. Subtract a day using the proper method, then recreate the format. Here's a reference for the methods you'd need: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Sorry, instead of "subtract a day", I meant "subtract 3 hours". Here's an example of what I mean anyways: http://jsfiddle.net/paHPK/1/

Comment: This is great if you add it as an answer I will mark it as correct! Thanks

Comment: Hmm actually it will break around new years-- I tried this: 01/01/2014 02:31 the function returned 00/31/2014 23:31

Comment: Ahh sorry. It's because months are 0 index based. Let me modify it so that 1 index based months are passed in and used properly

Comment: Thanks Ian and then please add it as a response so I can mark it as correct for others. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to do this manually, you can try the following:

1. Split by a space, so you have date and time.
2. Split the time by ":" and split the date by "/".
3. Create a `new Date()` and provide the right values in the right order.
4. Subtract 3 hours using the proper methods, then recreate the format.

Here's an example of all this:

```
var est = "01/01/2014 02:31",
    finalDate, pst;

finalDate = parseDateString(est);
finalDate.setHours(finalDate.getHours() - 3);
pst = formatDate(finalDate);

console.log(pst);

function parseDateString(str) {
    var dateTime, date, time, dateSplit, month, day, year, timeSplit, hour, minute;

    dateTime = est.split(" ");
    date = dateTime[0];
    time = dateTime[1];

    dateSplit = date.split("/");
    month = dateSplit[0] - 1;
    day = dateSplit[1];
    year = dateSplit[2];

    timeSplit = time.split(":");
    hour = timeSplit[0];
    minute = timeSplit[1];

    return new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute);
}

function formatDate(d) {
    return padZero(d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + padZero(d.getDate()) + "/" + d.getFullYear() + " " + padZero(d.getHours()) + ":" + padZero(d.getMinutes());
}

function padZero(num) {
    if (+num < 10) {
        num = "0" + num;
    }
    return "" + num;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/MmVmR/

The `padZero` function is there just to prepend any `0`s in case the number is less than 10.

Reference:

- Dates in JS - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date